# Sloppiness in Activity Diagrams

Tags: uml

As follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39572229/how-do-i-represent-nested-actions-in-a-uml-activity-diagram) I started digging in the UML specs regarding control flow in activity diagrams. Consider this simple example:

[image]

Notice that it neither has `ActivityInitial` nor `ActivityFinal`. I know (though I actually can't find the location) that the specs state that a flow is terminated when it has no outgoing edge. So if the `[terminate]` is passed the flow will stop after `Final` as if it has reached a `FlowFinal`. But - and here are my questions:

- Will similarly to a missing outgoing edge a missing ingoing edge mean that the flow has to start here? So in my example, will the flow start at `Implicit`?
- Since the `loop?` has only one guarded outgoing edge, what will happen to the token if it does not pass (I guess it will be stuck).
- Is a merge node required to join the edges from the `Decision` and the `Implicit` action into `Action`? (I guess you don't need it since an `Action` will accept all tokens that are offered and not wait like a `Join` would do for all to arrive.)

Please use citation from the recent UML specs in your answer.

Comment: In addition to the spec quote that would state about this question, I'd be curious to know how many people actually respect that. I've updated all my activity diagrams to add merging nodes in similar cases and I feel like I just ruined my diagrams' readability.

Comment: @TimF Yes. Jim is a good source for UML, but I guess in this case he was not right. Adding the merge is not wrong, but the readability is an important point.

Comment: @TimF,  I always make my merge nodes very small. These tiny diamonds don't really hurt readability.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl And how about the spec citation ? I've just been through the spec 2.5, fast-reading the action and activity parts and I didn't find this specificity.

Comment: @TimF: sergej just gave the answer: 15.5.3.1. See my comment on his answer.

Comment: Folks, please don't make your diagrams technically incorrect because you think they are more readable that way. That's like deciding to never use plurals in your writing because you don't like the way the S's look. There's a reason they exist.

Comment: @ThomasKilian, these are the most thoughtful questions I've seen about UML in a long time. I wish we could discuss these more often!

Comment: @JimL. I fully agree :-) I have (/had) a few more of those but they currently slipped my mind. I used to post them on a LinkedIn  forum in the past, but definitely will go the SO-way in the future. Interestingly this one has been migrated to Programmers. Really odd, since programmers are those person who usually ignore UML at most.

Comment: Indeed, they do!

Comment: Hrmph... who knew? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254571/2596664

Comment: @ThomasKilian, I don't know. I don't like starting over with reputation points, myself.

Comment: @JimL. I did not. Am I supposed to switch now? Is this new? Where should I ask all these questions? Don't tell me Meta - I only get bashed there. I could not resist to comment on the answer for the question you linked.

Comment: @JimL. I just posted this on Meta: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335039/why-has-so-an-uml-tag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Yes, the flow will start at `Implicit`. From the UML 2.5 specification:

   > #### [15.2.3.2 Activity Nodes]
   >
   > An ActivityNode is enabled to begin execution when specified conditions are satisfied on the tokens offered to it on incoming ActivityEdges...
   >
   > #### [15.2.3.6 Activity Execution]
   >
   > ... nodes that **do not have incoming edges** and require no input data to execute are **immediately enabled**.
2. The DecisionNode will be blocked from offering tokens on its outgoing edge.

   - As far as I understand, the specification does not mention what will happen to the token in detail. I guess saying "*the outgoing edge will be blocked and hence the token will get stuck*" is not too wrong.
     From the UML 2.5 specification:

     > #### [15.3.3.6 Decision Nodes]
     >
     > A token offered on the primary incoming edge of a DecisionNode shall not traverse any outgoing edge for which the
     >   guard evaluates to false.
   - For InitialNodes, the specification states the following:

     > #### [15.3.3.1 Initial Node]
     >
     > If the token offered by an InitialNode is not immediately accepted, or is otherwise **blocked from moving** downstream (for
     >   example by an ActivityEdge guard), then it **remains on the** InitialNode.
3. A MergeNode is required here, because the two incoming edges are *implicitly joined*, meaning that both edges must offer a token for the activity to begin execution. 
   From the UML 2.5 specification:

   > #### [15.5.3.1 Executable Nodes]
   >
   > An ExecutableNode shall not execute until all incoming ControlFlows (if any) are offering tokens. That is, there is an **implicit join** on the incoming Control Flows.

Comment: I don't understand 3. The join node is implicit, but a join is different from a merge, isn't it ? In this case we're more thinking of a merge behavior than of a join. A join has a synchronization meaning, which is exactly what Jim points as a blocking element, or have I not understood this ?

Comment: The 'implicit join' statement implies that, in Thomas' example diagram, that 'Action' will never be executed, because it waits for two tokens to arrive: one from 'Implicit' *and* one from itself, via the decision node. A merge node is required to get the intended behavior.

Comment: So Jim was right. I'd be curious to know why the people who wrote the spec have decided to take an implicit join instead of an implicit merge, which seems to be the intuitive understanding for many people, like Thomas and me. I think I'll go on forgetting this merging node. Bad me.

Comment: @TimF, In UML 1.x, there was an implicit merge. OMG has deliberately replaced this by an implicit join since UML 2.0. I think they did this, to be consistent with the incoming flows on an activity, where each incoming flow matches a parameter of the behavior. Obviously, a behavior may only commence when all parameters are available.

Comment: @TimF, UML 2.x is based on a well-known formalism called a [colored petri net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coloured_Petri_net). Referring to a well-known formalism makes UML 2 semantics more precise. Unless, of course, you abuse the notation, then nobody can be sure _what_ your diagrams mean.

Comment: @sergej, well done! You saved me from having to look all this up and provide an answer! :-)

Comment: @sergej, one thing that you say is true, but others may find confusing, is point (3). Thomas was really asking if a `MergeNode` is necessary, not a `JoinNode`. (A `JoinNode` is for forked threads, of which there are none.) As admiraalit points out in an above comment, "Action" will never execute because a `MergeNode` is missing, so the required two tokens will never arrive.

Comment: Thanks a bunch :-) Regarding 3: I read it the opposite way. In my example I'd expect `Action` to commence when the `loop?` passes on. But the passage you cite tells that there needs to be a merge since `Implicit` will only send a token once. So `Action` will not start. (P.S. exactly what @JimL. said)

Comment: @ThomasKilian, TimF, www.admiraalit.nl, Jim L, thanks for your comments, I should have read the question more carefully. I have edited the question, now talking about a merge node.